# Как с помощью Form:select передать значение а не ID?

Tags: laravel, form, select

Передаю список турниров `$tournaments` в `'trophies.admin.create'`

```
public function create()
{
    $championships  =   MasterChampionship::all()->lists('title');
    $cups           =   MasterCup::all()->lists('title');
    $tournaments    =   array_merge($championships,$cups,['EuropaLeague','ChampionsLeague','WorldCup']);

    return view('trophies.admin.create', compact('tournaments'));
}
```

В `'trophies.admin.create'` есть форма:

```
{!! Form::label('tournament', 'Tournament:') !!}
{!! Form::select('tournament', array('' => 'Please select one option') + $tournaments, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Эта форма возвращает индекс турнира. Как сделать что б возвращала значение?
Пример:

Получаю:

```
 Array
(
    [_token] => At7CNWdzlNf7XByLy4Fmpm1hA26ochfXDmKB5m9U
    [tournament] => 20
)
```

Надо:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => At7CNWdzlNf7XByLy4Fmpm1hA26ochfXDmKB5m9U
    [tournament] => 'EuropaLeague'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделайте ключи массива такие же как и значения, самый простой вариант через [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php):

```
$tournaments    =   array_merge($championships,$cups,['EuropaLeague','ChampionsLeague','WorldCup']);
$tournaments = array_combine($tournaments, $tournaments);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.